# Excel how to transfer cell background from one sheet to another?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I encountered a challenge with transferring the color and some specific values from this sheet:

[image]

The goal is to extract only the color from the sheet in the context of exam places. I attempted to use Name Manager, but unfortunately, it did not yield the desired results. Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

i tryed with namemanager but not worked.

Comment: If you are comfortable with VBA, you can write a macro to copy the format from one sheet and apply it to another.

Comment: So what happens if you unmerge the first rows of C and use copy paste formatting? Or copy row 5:15 and paste special: formatting in row 5 of the destination sheet.